Getting the value from multiple PDF and add them to Excel sheet
I am having kind of a problem right now with my current task for work.
I have a special program with a database of IT Equipment (laptop, screen etc.) for my company. The equipment is bound to a specific person in the company and this is saved in the database.
Now each person has to digital sign a PDF document with the listed serial numbers from the equipment and give it back to me. So I have an overview and can hold someone liable if he "loses" his equipment.
Now the problem.
I can export the data from the software to Excel to have a nice overview but I can't see who has signed his file and who didn't.
So I would like to grab the signed documents, load the data into the Excel file and let's say make the row green if it's signed.
The document is relatively simple. Each person has his unique number. It looks something like
Worker
WorkerID
Laptop
Serial
Screen
Serial
Signed
Another problem is I can't use any kind of scripting on work hardware except Excel VB
